# strip comments from xml file and pretty-print it

Tags: xml, bash, sh

I have this huge xml file which contains a lot of comments.

Whats the "best way" to strip out all the comments and nicely format the xml from the linux command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove XML comments using Regex in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230407/remove-xml-comments-using-regex-in-bash)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can use tidy

```
$ tidy -quiet -asxml -xml -indent -wrap 1024 --hide-comments 1 tomcat-users.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
  <user username="qwerty" password="ytrewq" roles="manager-gui" />
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Add "-modify" to the parameters to change the file in place. (You made a backup, right?)

Comment: BEWARE! There is a bug in tidy that removes spaces in XML so use the above answer with caution. Link to the open bug: https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/issues/818

Answer (score 11):

Run your XML through an [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) XSLT, with an empty template for comments.

All of the XML content, except for the comments, will be passed through to the output.

In order to niecely format the output, set the output @indent="yes":

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!--Match on Attributes, Elements, text nodes, and Processing Instructions-->
<xsl:template match="@*| * | text() | processing-instruction()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--Empty template prevents comments from being copied into the output -->
<xsl:template match="comment()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I use it with `<xsl:template match="@*| * | text() | processing-instruction() | comment()[contains(., 'licence')]">`

Answer (score 8):

You might want to look at the `xmllint` tool. It has several options (one of which `--format` will do a pretty print), but I can't figure out how to remove the comments using this tool.

Also, check out [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), a bunch of command line tools to do anything you would want to with xml. Then do:

```
xml c14n --without-comments # XML file canonicalization w/o comments
```

**EDIT**: OP eventually used this line:

```
xmlstarlet c14n --without-comments old.xml > new.xml
```

Comment: xmllint is a cmdline interface to libxml2, a library with bindings for many languages.  E.g. I use XML::LibXML in Perl.

Comment: I evntually used: xmlstarlet c14n --without-comments old.xml  > new.xml

Answer (score 3):

To tidy up something simple like Tomcat's server.xml, I use

```
sed 's/<!--/\x0<!--/g;s/-->/-->\x0/g' | grep -zv '^<!--' | tr -d '\0' | grep -v "^\s*$"
```

I.e.

```
function tidy() {
 echo "$( cat $1 | sed 's/<!--/\x0<!--/g;s/-->/-->\x0/g' | grep -zv '^<!--' | tr -d '\0' | grep -v "^\s*$")"
}

tidy server.xml
```

... will print the xml without comments.

NOTE: while it works reasonably well for simple things, it will fail with certain CDATA blocks and some other situations. Only use it for controlled xml scripts that have no need and will never need to escape a single `<--` or `-->` anywhere!

First sed marks comment's start and stop with 0x0 characters, then grep with `-z` treats 0x0 as the only line delimiter, searches for lines starting with comment, it's -v inverts the filter, leaving only meaningful lines. Finally, `tr -d`\0` deletes all these 0x0, and to polish it up, another grep removes empty lines: voila.

Answer (score -1):

The best way would be to use an XML parser to handle all the obscure corner cases correctly. But if you need something quick and dirty, there are a variety of [short solutions using Perl regexes](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=646970) which may be sufficient.

Comment: @reinierpost: I understand why this answer seems distasteful. But if this is a one-off, and you know your comments are a well constrained subset of the comment spec, then what's wrong with a regex solution? I agree a parsing tool is preferable (and is the best answer), but I do think this is a valid alternative in some specific situations (e.g. simple testing, or 2AM crisis callouts on a read-only system), and can be quite convenient.

Comment: With a valid XML and therefore only comments that are comments, I thinkan XML parser is better. However, if you handle HTML with comments that include conditions (i.e. think Internet Explorer) then a regex is probably your best bet.