# How to remove comments from Maven POM file

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have POM file with comments. I want to remove them during compilation time in Netbeans. I found that there is a maven plugin - maven-config-processor-plugin. But there is no information how I can remove the comments from the POM file? Is there any solution?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why would you want to remove the comments?

Comment: I like to comment my code but I don't like to include the comments in to the production code.

Comment: Not aware of a Maven solution. Check the following answer for details on how to strip comments from XML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464697/stripout-comments-from-xml

Answer (score 1):

Codehaus has an [xml maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/) that says it can transform XML files with XSLT stylesheets.  The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464697/stripout-comments-from-xml) @Mark O'Connor mentioned gives an example stylesheet.  Putting the two together may do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are translating your poms for "production", then you might perhaps wish to generate [**effective pom**](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) :

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

or

```
mvn help:effective-pom -Doutput=production-pom.xml
```

This not only removes comments, but also interpolates (=resolves) any property references, and applies `dependencyManagement` and `pluginManagement` from parent poms, which makes the pom quite "standalone".