# Remove XML comments using Regex in bash

Tags: xml, regex, bash

I want to remove XML comments in bash using regex (awk, sed, grep...) 
I have looked at other questions about this but they are missing something. Here's my xml code

```
<Table>
    <!--
   to be removed bla bla bla bla bla bl............

    removeee

    to be removeddddd
    -->

<row>
        <column name="example"  value="1" ></column>
    </row>
</Table>
```

So I'm comparing 2 xml files but I don't want the comparison to take into account the comments. I do this

```
diff file1.xml file2.xml | sed '/<!--/,/-->/d'
```

but that only removes the line that starts with `<!--` and the last line. It does not remove all the lines in between.

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse xml](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). Use a tool designed to parse xml. You could just use `tidy` or write an identity xslt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [stripout comments from xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464697/stripout-comments-from-xml)

Comment: @kojiro No sir. That question's answer uses `tidy`. Read my comment on @glennjackman answer

Comment: Consider improving the question by specifying that you are looking for a POSIX-compliant way to remove comments from XML, and not particularly a *regex* way (which, as has been documented thousands of times, is not an appropriate way to manipulate XML).

Comment: @kojiro Will do. thanks for guiding. Now, any suggestion for the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end, you're going to have to recommend to your client/friend/instructor that they need to install some kind of XML processor. `xmlstarlet` is a good command line tool, but there are any number (or at least some number greater than 2) of implementations of XSLT which can be compiled for any standard Unix, and in most cases also for Windows. You really cannot do much XML processing with regex-based tools, and whatever you do will be hard to read, harder to maintain, and likely to fail on corner cases, sometimes with disastrous consequences.

I haven't spent a lot of time polishing or reviewing the following little awk program. I think it will remove comments from compliant xml documents. Note that the following comment is *not* compliant:

```
<!-- XML comments cannot include -- so this comment is illegal -->
```

and it will not be treated correctly by my script.

The following is also illegal, but since I've seen it in the wild and it wasn't hard to deal with, I did so:

```
<!-------------- This comment is ill-formed but... -------------->
```

Here it is. No guarantees. I know that it's hard to read, and I wouldn't want to maintain it. It may well fail on arbitrary corner cases.

```
awk 'in_comment&&/-->/{sub(/([^-]|-[^-])*--+>/,"");in_comment=0}
     in_comment{next}
     {gsub(/<!--+([^-]|-[^-])*--+>/,"");
      in_comment=sub(/<!--+.*/,"");
      print}'
```

Answer (score 6):

The most simple solution to remove all comments from a textfile I could come up with is:

```
sed 's/<!--/\x0<!--/g;s/-->/-->\x0/g' | grep -zv '^<!--' | tr -d '\0'
```

To explain:

The `sed` will put in a `null` char like this:

```
<Table>
    \0<!--
   to be removed bla bla bla bla bla bl............

    removeee

    to be removeddddd
    -->\0

<row>
        <column name="example"  value="1" ></column>
    </row>
</Table>
```

Than the `grep -z` will treat that character as "line separator"

- `<Table>\n`
- `<!--\n   to be removed bla bla bla bla bla bl............\n\n        removeee\n\n    to be removeddddd\n    -->`
- `\n\n<row>\n        <column name="example"  value="1" ></column>\n    </row>\n</Table>\n`

`grep -v` will remove the middle part.

And finally `tr -d` will remove the `\0` again.

---

In this case it should be applied to both files before comparing e.g.:

```
diff <(sed 's/<!--/\x0<!--/g;s/-->/-->\x0/g' file1.xml | grep -zv '^<!--' | tr -d '\0') <(sed 's/<!--/\x0<!--/g;s/-->/-->\x0/g' file2.xml | grep -zv '^<!--' | tr -d '\0')
```

or more readable with a function:

```
stripcomments() {cat "$@" | sed 's/<!--/\x0<!--/g;s/-->/-->\x0/g' | grep -zv '^<!--' | tr -d '\0'}

diff <(stripcomments file1.xml) <(stripcomments file2.xml)
```

---

In theory there might be some issues with CDATA blocks, as they can be used to have unbalanced comments, and there is a higher probability of them having important null-characters, but I have never seen such an xml file in real life.

So for most valid xml-files this should work.

Comment: This is sufficient for most things you'd want to do.

Answer (score 4):

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//comment()' file.xml
```

Comment: Thankyou. But I am developing this script for someone and he will be running it on different linux and even solaris. So, not all linux have `xmlstarlet`. My main concern was to do it with regex maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pair 'perl-xmllint' to get this job done :

```
cat yourFile.xml | perl -e 'while (<>) { next if (/Start.*End/ );if (/Start/) { while (<>) {last if (/End/) }}else {print "$_"; }} ' | xmllint --format -
```

With Start = Your starting comment (in our case <!--)
     End = Your ending comment (in our case -->)

I tried to use grep -vP without any good results because I did not find how to tell grep to understand the dot as new lines (the s modifier).

Comment: it fails when there is a comment like this:
    <xmltag> <!-- comment that makes <xmltag> disappear -->

Answer (score 0):

this script use sed to handle replace.

```sh
sed -E  -e\
':start
/<!--/ {
   :loop
   /-->/ {
            s/-->/mockend102499883356/
            s/<!--.*mockend102499883356//
            /<!--/ {
                   b loop
            }
            b done
   }
   :add
   N
   b loop
   :done
}'  filename.xml;
```

by the way, this is a gnu sed edition. if not. it may do not work.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution using sed

```
 sed  '/<!--/,/-->/d' server.xml
```

**explanation:**

**d** - delete

**/<!--/** - Beginning from pattern <!--

**/-->/** - to pattern -->