# How to remove comment from XML using shell script

Tags: xml, shell

I would like to get port from server.xml that is tomcat server configuration file.

my server.xml is below.

How can I get port from server.xml without comment part

I just want to get only 50000 without 8080.

```
<Connector port="50000"  maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           maxThreads="2000" minSpareThreads="50" maxSpareThreads="150" />    
<!--
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
-->
```

Comment: Hi, Does any of the following answer helped you in your goal ? If it does please accept/upvote the answer for closure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove XML comments using Regex in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19230407/remove-xml-comments-using-regex-in-bash)

Comment: @Samuel Kirschner I have confirmed it. That's same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution to remove all comments from a textfile I could come up with is:

```
| sed 's/<!--/\x0<!--/g;s/-->/-->\x0/g' | grep -zv '^<!--' | tr -d '\0' |
```

To explain:

The `sed` will put in a `null` char like this:

```
<Connector port="50000"  maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           maxThreads="2000" minSpareThreads="50" maxSpareThreads="150" />    
\0<!--
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
-->\0
```

than the `grep -z` will treat that character as "line seperator" and remove the middle part, and finally `tr -d` will remove the `\0` again so that any following grep's won't treat it as a binary file.

just combine it with the grep you are already using e.g.:

```
 cat server.xml | sed 's/<!--/\x0<!--/g;s/-->/-->\x0/g' | grep -zv '^<!--' | tr -d '\0' | grep -o 'port="[0-9]*' | grep -o '[0-9]*$'
```

output:

```
50000
```

Answer (score 1):

The title is rather misleading, because what you really want is to extract the value of the "port"-attribute.
Please [don't use RegEx to parse XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858), but use an XML-parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) or [xmlstartlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstartlet) instead.

```
$ xidel -s server.xml -e '//@port'

$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//@port' server.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Following are different results , Please check look arounds for more details.

```
grep -oP 'port=.*? (?=maxHttpHeaderSize)' server.xml
port="50000"

grep -oP 'port=\K.*? (?=maxHttpHeaderSize)' server.xml
"50000"

grep -oP 'port="\K.*?(?="  maxHttpHeaderSize=)'
50000
```

Comment: In my case My server.xml is below state.
so I need to get only 50000 value.


`<Connector port="50000"  maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           maxThreads="2000" minSpareThreads="50" maxSpareThreads="150" />    
<!--
<Connector port="8080"  maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           maxThreads="2000" minSpareThreads="50" maxSpareThreads="150" />  
-->`

Comment: add this in question as in comments its difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bash script with sed. I think that it is the best solution with sed. if your system is OSX. (IE. macbook pro) you should install a gnu sed firstly.

```sh
sed -E  -e\
':start
/<!--/ {
   :loop
   /-->/ {
            s/-->/mockend102499883356/
            s/<!--.*mockend102499883356//
            /<!--/ {
                   b loop
            }
            b done
   }
   :add
   N
   b loop
   :done
}'  filename.xml;
```

this blog is the detail about the code. if you can read in chinese.
[remove xml comment in pom.xml of maven project](https://firfor.cn/articles/2021/10/31/1635673870523.html)