# delete html comment tags using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

The question was already [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055837/delete-html-comment-tags-using-regexp), but I noticed that the most popular answer is in fact wrong, and since the page still pops up #1 in google, I think it makes sense to comment on this. I cannot comment in the original discussion, because my reputation is too low, so if admins think that it should be moved there, please do it and do not panish me too hard))

So, we want to delete everything, which is denoted by html comment tags

```
This is how my text (html) file looks like
<!--
 |                                |
 |  This is a dummy comment       |
 |      please delete me          |
 |         asap                   |
 |                                |
  ________________________________
 | -->
```

The most voted answer suggested the following code

```
#! /bin/sed -f
# Delete HTML comments
# i.e. everything between <!-- and -->
# by Stewart Ravenhall <stewart.ravenhall@ukonline.co.uk>

/<!--/!b
:a
/-->/!{
    N
    ba
}
s/<!--.*-->//
```

While it works in simple cases, it fails when another comment starts at the same line, where previous one ends. For example, the input

```
<!--
1 --><!--
2 --><!--
3
-->
```

after applying the script above, will give

```
<!--
2 --><!--
3
-->
```

which means that only first comment will be deleted. The reason is that after substitution command is applied, the code does not check if the buffer also has the starting tag for the next comment.

The resolution to this problem is to modify the code like this

```
#! /bin/sed -f
:x
/<!--/!b
:a
/-->/!{
    N
    ba
}
s/<!--.*-->//
bx
```

or, in a short notation

```
cat file.html | sed ':x;/<!--/!b;:a;/-->/!{N;ba};s/<!--.*-->//;bx'
```

I thought it is important to correct this script, since it is listed on [seder's grab bag](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/)

A little bit more concise and very elegant solution was suggested by [Brian Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487099/brian-clements) (I've modified it a little)

```
cat file.html | sed ':a;s/<!--.*-->//g;/<!--/{N;ba}'
```

This one works fine, because even after substitution is done, the code checks if the beginning of the next comment is present. However it seems to me (correct me if i'm wrong) that this solution will be a little bit slower compared to the modified Stewart Ravenhall code, because the regular expression will be searched many times, even when it is not present, while the first script runs the search for regular expression only when it is definitely there.

Comment: Yes, but the two versions are unable to deal with two comments on the same line: `<!--abcd-->keepme<!--efgh-->`

Comment: [obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552) -- You should use an HTML parser to remove HTML comments.

Comment: Casimir, you are right, but I have no idea how to modify the script. As I understand, the problem arises because of sed regex being greedy. Does it mean that it is impossible to write in sed html comments removal script?

Comment: I [would use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15775791/1563512) `tidy -quiet -xml --hide-comments 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 'H
$ {g
   s/<\!--/²/g;s/-->/³/g
:a
   s/²[^³]*³//g
   t a
   s/.//p
   }' YourFile
```

- Assume `²`, `³` are not used inside html (if used, change the delimiter or adapte the code to change any occurence by a substitution string, and back at the end)
- don't take care of html tag in string like `" blabla <!--`
- any nested level is take into account (limited by sed buffer/memory used)