# sed - mult-line find and replace

Tags: linux, sed, devops

I'm trying to use sed to to essentially uncomment a section of code in Java Tomcat's server.xml file.  I'm having trouble with the multi-line find/replace to remove the XML comment tags.  Here is a snippet of the server.xml file:

```
<!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
     This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
     SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
     library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the
     AprLifecycleListener.
     Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
     the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
-->
<!--
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
-->
<!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
     This connector uses the APR/native implementation which always uses
     OpenSSL for TLS.
     Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used. OpenSSL style
     configuration is used below.
-->
<!--
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                     certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                     certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
-->

<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<!--
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
           address="::1"
           port="8009"
           redirectPort="8443" />
-->
```

and here is an example of one of the many attempts I've tried to perform the find/replace:

```
sed '/    <!--\n    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol/i test' /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml
sed '/<!--\n<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol/i test' /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml
sed '/*<!--\n*<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol/i test' /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml
```

Because there are a number of comment-tags, I have to associate it to the block I'm trying to uncomment which is why I'm trying to do the multi-line.

If anyone has any guidance on how to make this work with sed or another way to do it, I'd greatly appreciate it.

TIA!

EDIT1:  I've gotten it to work by using sed's line replacement but would rather not go that route since any future modifications to the file will change this operation.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a regex tool like sed to parse XML?

Comment: Not necessarily -- I'm just trying to use what's baked into my existing container rather than having to load something like perl/python.  We're trying to keep the containers as slim as possible.  Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464697/strip-comments-from-xml-file-and-pretty-print-it The answer literally mentions tomcat

Comment: And the answers remove all comment tags where I only want to remove one set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting it with two different seds:

```
## find the first 2 lines and replace with one to remove the start-comment:
sed -z 's/    <!--\n    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"/    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"/' /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml

## find the whole block (had to make sure I was removing the right closing-comment on the right block) and replace with the whole block, with modifications included, and comment removed:
sed -z 's/    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"\n               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">\n        <SSLHostConfig>\n            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf\/localhost-rsa.jks"\n                         type="RSA" \/>\n        <\/SSLHostConfig>\n    <\/Connector>\n    -->/    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"\n               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">\n        <SSLHostConfig>\n            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf\/tomcat.p12"\n                         certificateKeystorePassword="soopersecurepasswordtest"\n                         type="RSA" \/>\n        <\/SSLHostConfig>\n    <\/Connector>/' /opt/tomcat/conf/server.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your exact xml file format. Just give you an example for reference.

**The example XML file:**

```
$ cat foo.xml
<!-- real
     comment
-->

<!--
<foo a="1"
     uncomment="yes"
     b="2" />
</foo>
-->

<!--
<foo a="1"
     uncomment="no"
     b="2" />
</foo>
-->

<!--
<foo a="1"
     uncomment="yes"
     b="2" />
</foo>
-->
```

**The `sed` script:**

```
$ cat foo.sed
/^<!--$/! {
  p; b
}

h
:a
n; H
/^-->$/! ba

x
/uncomment="yes"/ {
  s/^<!--\n//
  s/\n-->$//
}

p
```

**Result:**

```
$ sed -nf foo.sed foo.xml
<!-- real
     comment
-->

<foo a="1"
     uncomment="yes"
     b="2" />
</foo>

<!--
<foo a="1"
     uncomment="no"
     b="2" />
</foo>
-->

<foo a="1"
     uncomment="yes"
     b="2" />
</foo>
```

<sub>(Use [sedsed](https://github.com/aureliojargas/sedsed) to see how it works in detail.)</sub>

Comment: I implemented the sed almost the same way, I just removed all of  the line start symbols (^) since they are spaced out a bit in my server.xml.  It returned the whole fiile, unchanged.